# Image is not rotating correctly in ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, video-editing, fluent-ffmpeg

This is the image having image rotation

[image]

I am trying to rotate the image 277 degrees and i am using the command which is

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i image.png  -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w=280:h=280, rotate=a=277.9791451500245:c=black@0[ovr1]; [0][ovr1]overlay=x=801.92161682248:y=639.210841671306:enable='between(t,0,3)'[v1]; [0:a]amix=1[mixout]" -map "[v1]" -frames:v 900 -map [mixout] output.mp4
```

By using this command not rotating the image properly, not only the image video elements also not rotating correctly and also changing the overlay position.
Can you help in this

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `a` is in radians, so you need to enter whatever `277*pi/180` computes to. Also, as `rotate` expands the video, the subsequent `overlay` must account for the expansion to make your overlaid image to pivot at a fixed pixel of itself. You kinda need to work out the math to use this combo of filters.

Comment: Yes i have tried by that rotate is working but overlay position is changing. can you tell me have any formula for that overlay